# ngShow not hiding view when argument is updated to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hide a part of my view after 3 secs with $timeout, but for some weird reasons this is not happening although the $scope value is updating.

```
$scope.failed = true;
$scope.des = res.data.description;
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.failed = false;
   $scope.loading = false;
   $scope.des = null;
   console.log($scope.failed);
}, 2000);
```

The template

```
<div class="done failed" ng-show="failed">
   <i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>
   <p>{{des}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: check if the template is in another scope. you can test this by calling a dummy function in scope in ng-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.status = {failed: true};
$scope.des = res.data.description;
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.status.failed = false;
   $scope.loading = false;
   $scope.des = null;
   console.log($scope.status.failed);
}, 2000);
```

The template

```
<div class="done failed" ng-show="status.failed">
   <i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>
   <p>{{des}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont know by heart, so to be bulletproof I had to google it. I think it has something to do with how the value is passed (as value or as reference). I have fallen too many times into this hole myself ... :)